How do i sync clerk users to supabase db
Currently I want to add a user automatically to supabasedb when a user is created.
I have tried to use this guide https://clerk.com/docs/integrations/webhooks/sync-data however when setting up the webhook I do not know what to put for the endpoint URL. I also do not know how to handle the data with supabase. enter image description here

Use localtunnel or ngrok to create your temporary endpoint and use it in the clerk webhook

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
